# Проблемы с WordPress плагином

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, error404, login

У меня проблема, я создаю доску объявлений с помощью плагина и плагин неплохой но есть какая-то проблема из-за которой не работает авторизация я найти причину ее не могу разработчик утверждают, что все хорошо, никаких ошибок на сайте не отражает однако есть в консоли следующее:

```
3(index):1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was
received.
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.
map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map:
HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
https://xn--b1afajfmtlk6t.com.ua/wp-content/plugins/directorist/public/assets/js/popper.min.js.
map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
https://xn--b1afajfmtlk6t.com.ua/wp-content/plugins/directorist/public/assets/js/bootstrap.min.
js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
https://xn--b1afajfmtlk6t.com.ua/wp-content/plugins/directorist/public/assets/js/jquery.barratin
g.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

Comment: То что у вас в консоли, первых несколько, это экстеншны хрома и это Source Maps, то что пониже, вроде как тоже Source Maps, только плагина. Вообще отсутствие Source Maps не должно никак влиять на работу сайта. Вы пробовали в других браузерах залогиниться?

Comment: Пасиба, да пробовал